# Greedy Quantifier problem with telnetlib's expect method

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture messages from a remote Linux machine which has approximately this format:

```
.*transmit message cmd: 0x1234, len: 20,
.*data: 00000000: 00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF
.*data: 00000010: 00 11 22 33 
.*receive message cmd: 0x1234, len: 0,
.*transmit message cmd: 0x1234, len: 0,
```

I've created a regex which captures what I want (a message, be it transmit or receive message) which is in principle like this:

```
 r'^.*(receive|transit).*message.*cmd(?P<cmd> [\da-fA-F]+,.*len(?P<len> \d+,(?:\n.*data:.*:.*)*'
```

with re.M flag.

That is find any line which contain 'receive' or 'transmit' and 'message' and could be potentially followed by N 'data' lines (provided msg's len is different to 0), that's why the last group could occur >= 0. When run against data from a file (thus offline analysis), this regex does its job. But the problem is when this regex is applied on live incoming streak coming from the Linux machine, as it is known that result of telnetlib.Telnet.expect() with a regex ending in a greedy quantifier is non-deterministic:

> If a regular expression ends with a greedy match (such as .*) or if
>   more than one expression can match the same input, the results are
>   non-deterministic, and may depend on the I/O timing.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/telnetlib.html

How to rewrite the regex so the deficiency of telnetlib is not hit? I thought of not searching for 'data' but anything that does not match to 'receive' or 'transmit', since this is then beginning of a new message.

Comment: Better yet: write a small parser for the incoming data. If you need help, provide some real world input and what you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the `*` matches non-greedy by appending a non-greedy indicator, e.g `.*?`

Here's a little more explanation about greedy vs. lazy: https://javascript.info/regexp-greedy-and-lazy

Comment: Thanks, I've already tried that, with the lazy variant it only matches 1st data line and that's it. the 2nd and next ones are not matched (this is to be expected as they are not greedy). The problem is the greedy one has to be avoided at the end of regex when used in expect() method. As when run against "live" data where is the end? For files this is easy: past and future are all there for inspection. As I noted for files the regex works like a charm.

Comment: No, never. `.*?` at the end of the pattern always matches an empty string. This suggestion is the same as suggesting to remove `.*` at the end of the pattern. Lazy quantifiers at the end of patterns always match the least amount of chars possible.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding that caveat in the expect() documentation, but I was speaking more towards the regex being able to match in multiple ways which produces non-deterministic results. With a non-greedy match, it will always pursue the smallest possible match, which solves that streaming problem

Comment: I believe you would need to know that there is a delimeter that could be matched at the end, for example an end-of-input or indication that the data you care about has ended.

Comment: Well one could use the 'len' captured from the message header it indicates how many bytes there are in the 'data' section, since each 'data' carries up to 16 bytes we could deduce the # of 'data' lines to follow. But this seems to me as an overkill solution.